# Model returning wrong predictions every single time for language translation

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, language-translation

I have used LSTM for designing a model for language translation. But even after 10000 entries in my data set, the model is not able to translate properly.

I have converted every word to small caps and have not removed any stop word. The training data is used as it is from the data set.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(src_vocab, n_units, input_length=src_timesteps,input_shape=trainX.shape,mask_zero=True))
model.add(LSTM(n_units))
model.add(RepeatVector(tar_timesteps))
model.add(LSTM(n_units, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(tar_vocab, activation='softmax')))
```

Ideally, this should have shown some translation if not actual but most of the times, it does not return maximum probability for any of the tokenized words and the string I get in the end is empty.
Here is the link for my [kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/amythshekhar/language-translation-error). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are plenty of things that might have gone wrong: conversion of tokens to indices, wrong hyper-parameter selection, wrong optimizer...

Comment: Here is the link to my [kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/amythshekhar/language-translation-error). Any help is appreciated